# Can I list all of the dataSources available?

Tags: grails, datasource, grails-2.0

I would like to iterate over all the available dataSources for the current environment, trying  to see if any of them contain a particular domain instance. Each environment has different dataSources.

The best I've hacked up so far is `grailsApplication.config.findAll { it.key.contains('dataSource_') }`. Is there a better or more legitimate way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also query against the bean names in the application context.

Something like

ctx.beanDefinitionNames.findAll{ it.contains( 'dataSource' ) }

At least that is what the DatasourcesUtils in the Datasources plugin does -

http://plugins.grails.org/grails-datasources/trunk/src/groovy/com/burtbeckwith/grails/plugin/datasources/DatasourcesUtils.groovy

Comment: seems like I was on the right track then. I was going to check the Datasources plugin but since multiple datasources is built-in to Grails 2 I thought it might have a better way.