# Can I get Tomcat context information in groovy (without getting the connection)?

Tags: tomcat, groovy, jndi

I am attempting to list all the databases that my application connects to. (And show whether they are online or not.) This information does exist in the Tomcat context file (JNDI Resource).  I can set the connection and get the information I need for those ones.... however if it does not connect, I would like to retrieve the URL for it to display.

```
DataSource dbSource = dbService.getDatasource()
String dbURL = dbSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL()
```

dbURL does display - but only if the connection works.  Is there a way to do this that does not require getting the connection?

Comment: Is this Grails?  If so, would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708067/can-i-list-all-of-the-datasources-available

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are really trying to monitor the database connection pool, right? This is what JMX was built for. Have a look at [Tomcat's monitoring FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring) and this presentation about [Monitoring Tomcat with JMX](http://home.apache.org/~schultz/ApacheCon%20NA%202015/Monitoring%20Apache%20Tomcat%20with%20JMX.pdf).

Comment: Yes, in a way, but through the GUI.  I want to list just the connection url if the connection fails (and therefore cannot have a connection being made to retrieve it).